# "Media" as a measure of central tendency

Tags: meta-analysis, median, central-tendency

I've just read a meta-analysis that used 'media' as a measure of central tendency: "The media of skin side events related to PPE was 75.13%". I've never come across the use of "media" like this  before- is this a typo, a variation on median, or is it something else?

Comment: I have never heard this term. Can you add a link to the paper?

Comment: It might be Latin for mean...

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai indeed it is, in Spanish at least.

Comment: The paper is here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jdv.17436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking further down the article we find the concept of media +- sd which strongly suggests it is the mean. The authors have Hispanic names and looking in the Dictionary of the Royal Academy we find

https://dle.rae.es/medio#QsIjfFA

> media aritmética
>
> 1. f. Mat. Resultado de dividir la suma de varias cantidades por el número de ellas.

Translation

> arithmetic mean
> feminine noun Mathematics. The result of dividing the sum of various quantities by the number of them